# Share Button Does Not Process the Whole Address and Title

Tags: url, facebook-sharer

I am using `share.php` on my sites, and I am trying to post this link: `http://www.obeczubri.cz/index.php?page=2&aktualita=25`

I am also trying to send title:

```
<a href='http://www.facebook.com/sharer.php?u=http://www.obeczubri.cz/index.php?page=".$_GET['page']."aktualita=".$radek[id]."&t=".$radek[titulek]."' target='_blank' style='text-decoration: none; color: grey;'><img src='admin/images/ikony/facebook_ikona.png' style='width: 15px; vertical-align: middle;'> <small>Sdílet na facebooku</small></a>
```

On mouse hover all looks ok as it should be but after it is on Facebook the link is incomplete. There in only part of it:
**Obec Zubří - Aktuality
http://www.obeczubri.cz/index.php?page=2**

There is missing part of the URL after my first `&`, and the title is also not corresponding.

Comment: Hi man, what do you please mean with **"escape your URL"**? Can you please show me some example? Thx.

Comment: I have found it and it works.Thx. Now my url is complete. Only description in still not displaying from url but from page title. Any idea please?

Comment: No more needed. I have found nice script. But thank you at all. The escape works.